# array_push fails on 10th iteration with identical code?

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-push

I am stymied by this and no SO posts mention this so I'm asking for some thoughts here. In essence, I have a evaluation survey with 13 questions and the data are stored on a single row using 13 columns (q1-q13). I extract the row and then iterate through each column looking for responses matching 3 or 2 or 1. When found, I write a row into an array using array_push. This works perfectly for columns 1-9 but it fails on the 10th. I copied/paste each line of code and made simple edits so, technically, each line of code is identical so I see no reason why it should fail. What am I missing here?

```
function get_POTENTIAL_List($sc_id) {
    global $dbc;

    $pot_list = [];

    $sql = "SELECT q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13 FROM worksheetA WHERE emp_id = ?";
    $stmt = prepared_query($dbc, $sql, [$sc_id]);
    $row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

Then I use this code to build the aray:

```
if($row['q1'] == "3" || $row['q1'] == "2" || $row['q1'] == "1") {
        $pot_info = array('id' => "1", 'category_title' => "INTRAPERSONAL/INTERPERSONAL", 'scale' => $row['q1'], 'scale_def' => "Scale Definition here.");
        array_push($pot_list, $pot_info);
    }
    if($row['q2'] == "3" || $row['q2'] == "2" || $row['q2'] == "1") {
        $pot_info = array('id' => "2", 'category_title' => "INTRAPERSONAL/INTERPERSONAL", 'scale' => $row['q2'], 'scale_def' => "Scale Definition here.");
        array_push($pot_list, $pot_info);
    }
```

and so on through (successfully) to 9:

```
if($row['q9'] == "3" || $row['q9'] == "2" || $row['q9'] == "1") {
        $pot_info = array('id' => "9", 'category_title' => "INTRAPERSONAL/INTERPERSONAL", 'scale' => $row['q9'], 'scale_def' => "Scale Definition here.");
        array_push($pot_list, $pot_info);
    }
```

And then, on the 10th column it stops working with a

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

error.

```
if($row['q10'] == "3" || $row['q10'] == "2" || $row['q10'] == "1") {
        $pot_info = array('id' => "10", 'category_title' => "INTRAPERSONAL/INTERPERSONAL", 'scale' => $row['q10'], 'scale_def' => "Scale Definition here.");
        array_push($pot_list, $pot_info);
    }
```

Comment: Please add in the complete error message, and indicate the line where the error is indicated. There's no JSON or functions thereof anywhere in the code you have shared.

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" is a JavaScript error, not a PHP error. Are you using some JavaScript to read this data when PHP finishes outputting it? And how do you know it's the q10 code in the PHP which causes that error? It's a bit unclear, especially as there's no JS and you've posted disconnected snippets of PHP. You'll need to provide a [mre] of the issue before we can help properly. P.S. as an aside, your database structure appears to be highly denormalised, which has likely given rise to this overly repetitive code. Consider a database redesign.

Comment: Yes, this was being called through Ajax and it was the return that was failing. In regard to the database structure, I THOUGHT I had been following the 'rules' of normalizing my database and because the survey responses are captured on a single person I thought this was the right way to do this. Now you have me wondering so I will go back and take another look. Thanks!

Comment: Well obviously I can't see the rest of your schema or anything relating to people, but from what I _can_ see, I'd be expecting you'd have a "worksheets" table, and then the questions belonging to each sheet would be rows in a separate "questions" table (which has a foreign key back to the sheets table). If you find yourself repeating the same kind of columns (e.g. question1, question2, question3) in the same table, it's usually a sign of incomplete normalisation. Also if you have a "worksheetA" table, do you also have a "worksheetB" table, etc? Multiple similar table is another bad sign.

Comment: Great input that I will look at. worksheetA was just a placeholder so no "worksheetB" ...

Answer (score 1):

Problem found. It was an 'em-dash' in the test string for the actual Scale Definition 'scale_def' used for question 10. Duh! Learning lesson for me.

Comment: Sounds like just a typo, so the question is unlikely to be much use to others. Consider deleting it instead. A typo mistake is a specific closure reason on Stackoverflow questions. Thanks.

Comment: How do I delete? Google tells me there should be a delete "at the bottom of the post" but the 'delete' I see is a "vote to delete" button.

Comment: Hm, you might need to delete this answer first. https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question (and linked articles) has more info.

Comment: The info under your link implies that as long is there are any responses the post can't be deleted. Maybe I should edit the first line in my question to preempt any wasted effort.

Comment: Like I said, delete this answer first, and then the question should be deletable.  Comments don't count.